# How to avoid adding a new Windows Firewall exemption every time an application is updated using Squirrel.Windows?

Tags: electron, squirrel.windows

Whenever a fresh client is installed the request is generated for firewall access. On new install its acceptable.

As the application is updated, the exe location is changed and again the user gets a prompt for firewall access. That seems irritating.

Is there any solution for this problem?

The problem is that every time an application is updated, the user has to add (accept) a new firewall exemption.

I think we can fix this issue patching Squirrel.Windows in such a way so that Windows OS able to understand that it's the same application, not a different one on every update.

[image: Firewall exemption Window]

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get around this, is to sign your application using a a code-signing certificate: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/using/application-signing.md